# How to prevent sanitization of textarea value attribute in Svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte

```
<textarea value={@html value}></textarea>
```

Throws an error `Unexpected character '@'`. How can I prevent sanitization of a value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@html` is for HTML within an element.
Here you do not have to escape/unescape anything, the `textarea` accepts any HTML, E.g.

```html
<script>
    let value = '<p>Hi</p>';
</script>

<textarea bind:value />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/696f25f557ac437498c4f34a7110e412?version=3.48.0)

If you want to render and edit HTML that is another can of worms that requires a regular element like a `div` and [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). There are many libraries that implement rich text editing.